# Public Storage Folder API 30 Android 11

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Android 11,

I'm trying to create a publicly accessible folder I can store my media files within, which will contain 1 folder and 1 text file per game type (there could be many), I do not want *any* other application to have access to the root folder for the exception of file explorers, as the user 'could' have content inside the folder that is R18 restricted or might not, I'm not in control of what content goes in there, it would be nice if I could provide that so that a child doesn't in mistakenly bump into the content while looking for pictures on the device for barnie.

I found some code on GitHub that did just the above on Android 10 and works flawlessly for Android 10, but cannot find anything but blue pills about it when it comes to Android 11, help in the form of example code would be great, yes I know targeting only Android 11 limits me but I'd rather live with the limit than play with many different versions of code.

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).apply {
    flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
}
startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_FOLDER_REQUEST_CODE)
```

**EDIT 2**

After some hacking around, because 'startActivityForResult(Intent!, Int): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java, I end up with this, results is a URI, can I now use this to pass files to other API calls now?

```kotlin
pref = getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
var userFolderData: String? = pref.getString("userFolderData", "")

if (userFolderData=="") {
    val getUserFolderData =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree()) {
            mytools.debug(it.toString())
            pref.edit().putString("userFolderData",it.toString()).apply()
            userFolderData = it.toString()
        }
    getUserFolderData.launch("".toUri())
}
mytools.debug("userFolderData = ${userFolderData}")
```

**EDIT 3**

So I ran a test on the URI returned; always the same story not matter what I do, yes that's pretty ugly hack but it's the easiest way I can find to test it.

```
ivtitleimage.setImageURI("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ATest%2FMelsDeck%2Fbendover01.jpg".toUri())
```

31833-31833/com.example.cardgamexxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.cardgamexxx, PID: 31833
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cardgamexxx/com.example.cardgamexxx.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{5a390cf 31833:com.example.cardgamexxx/u0a741} (pid=31833, uid=10741) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs

**EDIT 4**

Right, so user selects folder/creates one with `registerForActivityResult` code above, I place files in it with Cx File Explorer and automagically drum roll! ...

I do not have read access to the file placed there, anyway thought I'd comment here as I don't want people stumbling on the post and thinking this works, because it doesn't.

Comment: `trying to create a publicly accessible folder` Ok . `I do not want any other application to have access to the root folder` What is 'the root folder'? And what is the connection with your public accessable folder?

Comment: @blackapps best way I can describe what I'm trying to do, is by example;("www.mycardgame.com/") would be the root of the folder, or user selected folder of their own naming/location (probably preferred, maybe even best practice), but lets say www.mycardgame.com/ exists the user could throw their own media in it by means of a file explorer or I could use it to deploy default media that comes with the game, but video/image & audio placed there do not appear to applications such as 'gallery' it's annoying even seeing my test file, as they are X rated but will not come with the game if launched.

Comment: Sorry,... that was not helpfull. I dont understand a word.

Comment: @blackapps belaboring the point maybe, a lot of applications have there own folder seemingly on my Android 11 device, /storage/emulated/self/primary/ _appears_ to be the location where they hang out.

Comment: That would be the path of Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() then. Or such.

Comment: 'getExternalStorageDirectory(): File!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java -- I'd rather not use, as it's going away at some point.

returns path;
/storage/emulated/0

Comment: @MelonySharon, `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` is deprecated. This is for accessing files like in `Pictures` folder, that is accessible from every app. `getExternalFilesDir` is **not** deprecated. This is for storing files inside your own app. And this files could be only accessed from your app.

Comment: Actually : getExternalFilesDir() gets /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.cardgamexxx/files/ which is an internal directory inside your app and not accessible from the outside world, it may have returned something different prior to Andriod 11.

Comment: To access external files with Android 11 you need to use `MediaStore`

Comment: thanks @anatoli I just got done writing that code, I've asked for opinions of it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68466390/get-image-from-media-store-by-name here.

Answer (score 0):

On an Android 11 device your app can only create folders on root of external storage in the classic way if it has requested 'all files acces'.

Or it can use Storage Access Framework and for instance ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user create a folder in root of external storage and then select it.

Comment: Since I do not need 'MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' more over will get denied by Google Play, I guess that leaves one option 'ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE' ?

Comment: And ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE (while might work), startActivityForResult() is also on googles chopping block, I believe registerForActivityResult() is what is supposed to replace it, but I don't see how that helps this situation.

Comment: There is a replacement for the latter. And i did not say you had to use that. It's deprecated but it works fine.

Comment: `I believe registerForActivityResult() is what is supposed to replace it, but I don't see how that helps this situation.` Well that makes not any difference. As said: the user can create the wanted folder and select it. I dont understand why you see a problem that does not exist. I cannot follow you.

Comment: While I can use registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) for obtain a URI, I don't see how that helps a user select a folder/create one for my application to use for it's media, because I've never seen code that uses that way, because my experience is limited to using that for GetContent().

Comment: Using startActivityForResult and ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE the user can create and select a folder. Are you now telling that switching to registerForActivityResult(ActivityResult and ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE  that is not possible anymore?