# Get Image from media store by name

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mediastore

Would like some opinions of this code, personally it would be nice to go directly to the file rather than looping through what could be a massive list of files that's my only gripe with it.

Keep in mind you'll need to request READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE both in manifest and in code before this will actually work.

version 0.1

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Get Image Content URI from MediaStore based FileName
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fun getImageFromMediaStore(appContext: Context,findFileByName : String = ""): Uri {

    val imageProjection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                                  MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)

    val cUri = Uri.parse("")

    val cursor = appContext.contentResolver.query(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        imageProjection,
        null,
        null,
        null
    )

    cursor.use {
        it?.let {
            val idColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
            val nameColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
            while (it.moveToNext()) {
                val id = it.getLong(idColumn)
                val name = it.getString(nameColumn)
                val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    id)

                if(findFileByName == name) {
                    mytools.debug("Images: $id $name $contentUri")
                    return contentUri
                }
            }
        }?: kotlin.run {
            Log.e("TAG", "Cursor is null!") }
    }
    return cUri
}
```

idea for bettering my code?

mytools.debug() replace with Log.d() I missed my PureBasic command Debug() so I made my own :P

Version 0.2

```
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Get Image Content URI from MediaStore based FileName
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fun getImageFromMediaStore(appContext: Context,findFileByName : String = ""): Uri {

    val imageProjection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                                  MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)

    val cUri = Uri.parse("")

    val cursor = appContext.contentResolver.query(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        imageProjection,
        null,
        null,
        null
    )

    cursor.use {
        it?.let {
            val idColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
            val nameColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
            while (it.moveToNext()) {
                val id = it.getLong(idColumn)
                val name = it.getString(nameColumn)
                val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    id)

                if(findFileByName.contains("content:",true)) {
                    // *** DIRTY LITTLE HACK! ***
                    val hackedUriId = findFileByName.split("%3A").toTypedArray()
                    val hackedId = hackedUriId[1].toLong()
                    if (hackedId == id) {
                        return contentUri
                    }
                    // *** DIRTY LITTLE HACK! ***
                } else {
                    if (findFileByName == name) {
                        mytools.debug("Images: $id $name $contentUri" )
                        return contentUri
                    }
                }
            }
        }?: kotlin.run {
            Log.e("TAG", "Cursor is null!") }
    }
    return cUri
}
```

Included dirty hack to take the result of a Uri returned by this by this code and give back an actual Uri, that can be saved to a file and used later.

```
        val getContentCardImage = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent())  { uri: Uri? ->

        Log.d("EditCards","URI = "+uri.toString())
    }
    getContentCardImage.launch("image/*")
```

Comment: `null,
        null,
        null` You should use selection and selection arguments.

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68361660/3237946) answer. Exactly, `getFileUri` would help you.

Comment: @anatoli Interesting.. I'll do some work on how it functions; kind of like my functions though quite proud of that little hack :D, have to be careful what I use as I'm strict Android 11 / Api 30 only.